# Could not establish trust relationship wso2 ESB

Tags: ssl, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

Hello I am consuming a proxy via http, so I was surprised when I saw this error:

Could not establish trust relationship

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)...
```

For the an ASP.NET web App:

```
            Example1 es = new Example1();
            try
            {
                int result = es.checkUserExists("bob");
                TextBox1.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                TextBox1.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
```

My Proxy is the following:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Example1" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="STATUS" value="asking_id" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="insequence****" value="This is the in sequence"/>
            <property xmlns:ns2="http://chi/" name="property_arg0" expression="//ns2:checkUserExists/arg0"/>
         </log>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://192.168.10.176:8080/Example1/UserExist/"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <switch source="get-property('STATUS')">
            <case regex="asking_id">
               <log level="full">
                  <property name="sequence*******" value="outSequence - STATE 01 - asking for balance"/>
                  <property xmlns:ns2="http://chi/" name="property_result******" expression="//ns2:checkUserExistsResponse/return"/>
                  <property name="status********" expression="get-property('STATUS')"/>
               </log>
               <property xmlns:ns2="http://chi/" name="id_result" expression="//ns2:checkUserExistsResponse/return" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
               <enrich>
                  <source type="inline" clone="true">
                     <ns2:getBalancebyID xmlns:ns2="http://chi/">                        
                        <arg0 xmlns="">?</arg0>                     
                     </ns2:getBalancebyID>
                  </source>
                  <target type="body"/>
               </enrich>
               <enrich>
                  <source type="property" clone="true" property="id_result"/>
                  <target xmlns:ns2="http://chi/" xpath="//ns2:getBalancebyID/arg0"/>
               </enrich>
               <property name="STATUS" value="response" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
               <send>
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="http://192.168.10.176:8080/Example1/UserBalance"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </case>
            <case regex="response">
               <log level="full">
                  <property name="sequence*******" value="outSequence - STATE 02 - returning balance"/>
               </log>
               <send/>
            </case>
         </switch>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL key="conf:/UserExist.xml"/>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

Any suggestion why I cannot consume the Proxy?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your endpoint URL should point the service..Not the wsdl link<send><endpoint address uri="http://.../UesrExist"/> </send>

Comment: still not works unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to .Net App..There are number of sources available regarding this issue

eg:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823177